# How can I fix my collisions for a platformer type game?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision

I'm using OpenGL, EnTT, and C++ to try and recreate Super Mario World. Currently, when I move the player in one direction and it collides with a solid block, the collision detection and resolution works well. However, when the player tries to jump whilst constantly moving towards a wall, the top collision gets triggered, causing the player to stop and fall back down. I've searched the internet for a while now but I just couldn't resolve this issue. I'd appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Collision Code:

```
void GameUI::collision(const entt::entity &entity, const entt::entity &object) {
    const auto &ent {registry.get<Hitbox>(entity)};
    auto &phys {registry.get<Physics>(entity)};
    const auto &obj {registry.get<Hitbox>(object)};

    if (ent.btm >= obj.top || ent.top <= obj.btm
        || ent.left >= obj.right || ent.right <= obj.left)
        return;

    if (ent.btm < obj.top && ent.btm - phys.yVel >= obj.top) { // Bottom Collision
        moveY(entity, obj.top - ent.btm);
        phys.yVel = 0;
    } else if (ent.top > obj.btm && ent.top - phys.yVel <= obj.btm) { // Top Collision
        moveY(entity, obj.btm - ent.top);
        phys.yVel = 0;
    } else if (ent.left < obj.right && ent.left - phys.xVel >= obj.right) { // Left Collision
        moveX(entity, obj.right - ent.left);
        phys.xVel = 0;
    } else if (ent.right > obj.left && ent.right - phys.xVel <= obj.left) { // Right Collision
        moveX(entity, obj.left - ent.right);
        phys.xVel = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by defining exactly what _should_ happen.  Identify what's actually happening, either by setting a breakpoint or writing data to console or file.  I suspect that what you're experiencing is that the player moves inside the wall and has both `x` and `y` velocities, and since your "top" test happens first, you only process that and then exit.  If you wish to collide on both axes independently, then remove the `left < right` test.  Maybe that will get you closer to whatever it is you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do any bound checking to see if you're *actually* crashing into the wall in any given direction. When the function detects that you are clipping (and does not return right off the top), this is what happens.

```
      The actual wall -->  ######### ------------ <-- The plane where the wall lies
                                   # o_
                                   # /\    <-- You, hitting your head on the top plane
                                   #  |\
                                   #
                                   # | | |
```

Because the top collision is checked *before* the side ones.

```
if (ent.top > obj.btm && ent.top - phys.yVel <= obj.btm)
```

Even though you may not be clipping through the bottom of the wall, you are:

- Inside the wall (function does not return right away)
- Below its top side
- And have an upward velocity

... Which includes all the conditions for a detection of a top-side collision.